# C# use of unassigned local variable inside an if loop

Tags: c#, loops, variables, undefined, local

since I'm a bloody beginner, I'll need some help here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gauss_Algorithmus
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (x1 > 0 && x2 > 0)
            {
                 x02 = (x2 * x1) - (x1 * x2); 
                 y02 = (y2 * x1) - (x1 * y2);
                 z02 = (z2 * x1) - (x1 * z2);
                 d02 = (d2 * x1) - (x1 * d2);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("2.:   " + x02 + "x + " + y02 + "y + " + z02 + "  d02);
       }
   }
```

It says:

> Use of unassigned local variable "x01, etc....

I understand the error and know that `x01` is just defined in a local scope, but don't know how to fix it since `x01`, etc. needs to be defined inside the `if` loop.

I hope you can help me out guys, thanks in advance..

Comment: Those variables are never defined, so kinda hard to discuss; the definition position is critical here (as is the exact position where things are assigned values). Can you edit it to show a version that at least shows the same error as the one you are reporting?

Comment: And you never use `x01` either, which means this isn't the code producing this error. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: you are also missing a `}` that would close the scope of the `namespace` function

Answer (score 1):

The best advise is to do a getting started with C# tutorial.

Specifically answering your question there are two things wrong:

1. You need to declare the variables. Basically using `var x02 = (x2 * x1) - (x1 * x2);`  etc
2. The usage of the variables needs to be in the same scope. Either you have to move the `Console.WriteLine` inside the `if` block or you need to declare and initialize the variables before the `if` block like this: `var x02 = 0;` etc

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier, see a good C# tutorial for beginners.

To make your example code work, do the following:

Declare variables first, maybe of integer types, e.g

```
int x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2, d1, d2, x02, y02, z02, d02;
```

Initialize them before using, e.g 
 `x1 = *value*; y1 = *value* ...`

Reformat the Console.WriteLine statement, e.g: 
 `Console.WriteLine("2.: {0}", x02);  //for displaying value of x02`